# Can't build mod_fcgid because apxs no longer shipped by Apple?

Tags: high-sierra, apache

[Mac OS 10.13.2]
I'm trying to setup the standard `Apache` version (2.4.28) that comes with Mac OS to run `mod_fcgid` but I can't find it anywhere, nor can I build it from source. I wish I had done this earlier as I wouldn't have this problem now.

`mod_fcgid` has gone missing from Homebrew since they've reorganised the `Homebrew/homebrew-apache` repository and emptied it without indicating where all its contents have gone (like they've drunk the wine and are giving away the empty bottle):

```
user@host:[13:15]$ brew tap Homebrew/homebrew-apache
Warning: homebrew/apache was deprecated. This tap is now empty as all its formulae were migrated.
```

*For reasons beyond my control, I'm using Homebrew as the 'package manager' that Apple doesn't want to supply, and thus can't use `Mac Ports`.*

I can't build `mod_fcgid.so` (even though I have the source) because, Apple in its 'infinite wisdom', have decided to no longer ship `apxs` on High Sierra (*it's worth looking further into this as I'm sure you'll find some surprises you weren't aware of*), which is a required component of the Apache build toolchain.

Anyone know how to get `mod_fcgid.so` on High Sierra?

Comment: I've built apache2.4.28 from source, and I get `apxs` as part of the output.  However, when using `httpd -V`, the build is not the same as that delivered with High Sierra.  High Sierra has `-D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE` but my build has `-D APR_USE_SYSVSEM_SERIALIZE`.  Which `configure` flag is responsible for this setting choice?

Comment: Using the generated `apxs`, I was able to build `mod_fcgid.so`.  However, when referencing it from the httpd.conf file, the following error message is displayed when `apachectl -t` is executed: `Symbol not found: _ap_unixd_setup_child\n  Referenced from: /opt/apache2/modules/mod_fcgid.so\n  Expected in: flat namespace\n in /opt/apache2/modules/mod_fcgid.so`